# SQL Partition Order By not sorting Decimal value correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to order a record so that the latest date, and the highest value populate first and then decrease in a descending order.

This is what I've written:

```
SELECT contact__c,
       Ind_Assets_Retail__c,
       lastmodifieddate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY contact__c
                         ORDER BY lastmodifieddate, ind_assets_retail__c DESC) as row_num
FROM contact_financial__c
```

I  tried isolating for just the date (lastmodifieddate) it was able to properly order the dates in descending order, but when I isolate the Order by clause to just the second field (ind_assets_retail__c) it doesn't order them logically.

The ind_assets_retail__c field is a decimal value. I've also tried to cast it as decimal in the query and it still did not return the results I wanted.

This is the result I get when I run the query:

| contact__c | Ind_Assets_Retail__c | lastmodifieddate | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 0.00 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 1 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 0.00 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 2 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 38641.91 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 3 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 38641.91 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 4 |

This is the result I actually want

| contact__c | Ind_Assets_Retail__c | lastmodifieddate | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 38641.91 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 1 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 38641.91 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 2 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 0.00 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 3 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 0.00 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 4 |

Comment: What is the data type of the column?  I also don't understand.  Are the results for the specified query or a different query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is decimal value! The results are for the specified query

Comment: Please provide a db fiddle with reproduces the issue.

Comment: There must be some other factor you're not sharing, your data and query as presented [works exactly as expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a47299f6022f97d1aca401870b1bbdde)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the date column has a milliseconds component that you do not see.  Try converting just to a date:

```
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contact__c
                      ORDER BY CONVERT(date, lastmodifieddate), ind_assets_retail__c DESC
                     ) as row_num
```

Comment: Just tried this, it is still producing the same incorrect order (table 1 in question)

Comment: @JulieNguyen please provide a [mre] i.e. the exact SQL including DDL+DML - easy to do using dbfiddle.